# Linear CRF is to LR what _____ is to RF/SVM

Tags: svm, random-forest, structured-prediction

This figure from (1) shows the relation between LR and linear CRF: linear CRF is pretty much the generalization of logistic regression to sequences:

[image]

Is there any established generalization of random forest or SVM to sequences?

---

(1) Sutton, Charles, and Andrew McCallum. "[An introduction to conditional random fields](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/csutton/publications/crftut-fnt.pdf)." Machine Learning 4.4 (2011): 267-373.

Comment: RF and SVMs are very different, there is no generalization going from one to another. RF operates an ensemble of trees while SVM operates support vectors while maximizing the margin.

Comment: @xeon shall I split it into 2 different questions, one about SVM, one about RF?

Comment: Yes and no. The difference with CRF and Logistic Regression that they both can be cast in a common framework and *only* then differences/similarities are pointed out. To my knowledge RF and SVM cannot be easily cast into a same framework.